# Error with angularcli / webpack / materialize project

Tags: css, angular, sass, materialize

I get this error multiple times upon build :

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../fonts/roboto/Roboto-Bold.woff' in 'C:\Users\Administrateur\Documents\dev\angular\ProjectDemo\node_modules\materialize-css\sass'
 @ ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":false,"precision":8,"includePaths":[]}!./node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss 6:78441-78484
 @ ./node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss
 @ multi ./node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss ./src/assets/scss/main.scss
```

I don't understand what is going on ? Can someone explain it to me ?

Comment: Possibly there is a loading issue with your `Roboto font`. Did you checked with it?

Comment: The roboto font in question is from materialize-css which is a npm module. I don't use it anywhere, for now i'm just trying to config the project. I've already used webpack and materialize and never had this kind of issue :/

Comment: If so, then you should try to re-install the node_module.